# Preventing jQuery from escaping when setting the contents of a text area

Tags: jquery

I am putting some already escaped text onto the page and then setting the contents of a textarea using jQuery with that text. But it is being escaped again. I don't want to not escape the text going onto the page as it is user input text from the database.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('#load-template-link').click(function (event) {
    var content = jQuery('#template-' + jQuery('#template_selector option:selected').val());

    if (content.length > 0) {
        jQuery('#text-area').val(content.html());
    }

});
</script>

{% for template in templates %}
<script type="text/template" id="template-{{ template.id }}">{{ template.body }}</script>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If by `escape` you mean convert html to entities then it is the `.html` function that is doing that.  Use `.text`:

```
> $("<div>&></div>").html()
"&amp;&gt;"
> $("<div>&></div>").text()
"&>"
```

Comment: I tried using content.text() and it made no difference it seems to be the val() that is doing the escaping

Answer (score 0):

You tried using text() instead of html() ?

```
content.text()
```